# How to get CircleCI status badge for particular branch

Tags: github, circleci, badge, readme

I have a CircleCI badge in my readme file, which is just retrieved via:

```
<img src="https://circleci.com/gh/ORESoftware/live-mutex.png?circle-token=8ee836581">
```

is there a way to retrieve the badge for just a certain branch? Is there a way to keep it updated? Sometimes it lags - probably because of http caching.

Comment: The [incorrect caching of build badges](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/badge-shows-incorrect-status/29790) has been a sporadic issue on CircleCI for quite some time, but I don't think they've ever had a reliable enough test case to be able to trace the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was only a matter of putting `?branch=dev` in the query params like so:

```
<img src="https://circleci.com/gh/ORESoftware/live-mutex.png?branch=dev&circle-token=8ee836581">
```

Comment: `.../live-mutex.png/dev` - see https://shields.io/category/build

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [Status Badges page](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/status-badges/) in your CircleCI project's notifications setting section?

You should be able to build a badge for your specific branch via the `Branch` dropdown:

> By default, the badge displays the status of your project’s default branch. If you want to show the status of a different branch, use the Branch dropdown menu to select it.

Comment: I saw that docs page, I cannot find the page to actually get the badge url.  That will drive some one crazy. How is there not a link in the docs to the page in the app that can do that is beyond me.

Comment: Incredible this can't be copied from the ui.. It has repo oAuth

Comment: I had the same issue - just got it working to use my develop branch - I had to add /tree/develop:  

[![CircleCI](https://circleci.com/gh/<ORG_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/tree/develop.svg?style=svg&circle-token=<TOKEN>)](<LINK>)